# Display cropped thumbnail not featured image

Tags: images

Currently i have these lines in functions.php and my home page respectively:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'square', 252, 252, true );
```

//

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()):
      the_post_thumbnail( 'square' );
    endif;
```

Then regenerate thumbnails plugin resizes images to 252 x 252.

How do I display cropped thumbnail images and not featured?

Just to add , im using ACF custom fields plugin and part of that tinkers with the featured iamges, so it maybe possibly re-writing native  logic in how to handle images. If anyone has been in a similar situation, please let me know if ou found a work around. Thanks!

Comment: The code looks correct. The issue must be somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try with this code.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 252, 252, true);
```

//enter code here

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()):

      the_post_thumbnail();

endif;
```

OR

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()):

      the_post_thumbnail(array(252, 252));

endif;
```